# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to in spring boot microservice

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch the matched string character by using spring data jpa query method and spring boot. When I am implementing this , I am getting the error like the following,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.spacestudy.model.RoomInvestigatorMapping
```

My service file containes the following code,

```
public List<String> retrieveReponsiblePerson(String sEmpName)
{
    List<RoomInvestigatorMapping> roomInvestigatorListResultObj = roomInvestigatorMappingRepositoryObj.findInvestigatorUsingName();

    List<String> roomInvestigatorListReturnObj = new ArrayList<>();

    for (RoomInvestigatorMapping result : roomInvestigatorListResultObj) 
    {
        String subStringRoomInvestigator = result.employee.sEmpName;
        if (subStringRoomInvestigator.contains(sEmpName)) 
        {
            List<String> obj = new ArrayList<>();
            obj.add(subStringRoomInvestigator);
            roomInvestigatorListReturnObj.addAll(obj);
        }
    }
    return roomInvestigatorListReturnObj;
}
```

And I am calling this method from controller file like the following,

```
@GetMapping("/loadResponsiblePersons")
public List<String> loadResponsiblePersonsMethod(
        @RequestParam(value = "sEmpName", required = true) String sEmpName) 
{
    return roomServiceObj.retrieveReponsiblePerson(sEmpName);
}
```

And my repository file containes the following,

```
@Repository
public interface RoomInvestigatorMappingRepository extends JpaRepository<RoomInvestigatorMapping, Integer>{

// find RoomInvestigatorMapping details by id
@Query(" select new map(emp.sEmpName as sEmpName, emp.nEmpId as nEmpId, "   
        + "roomInvest.nRoomInvestigatorMappingId as nRoomInvestigatorMappingId, "
        + "roomInvest.nRoomAllocationId as nRoomAllocationId) "
        + "from RoomInvestigatorMapping as roomInvest Inner Join Employee  as emp "
        + "on roomInvest.nInvestigatorId  = emp.nEmpId ")
List<RoomInvestigatorMapping> findInvestigatorUsingName();
}
```

Error stack like the following when I am calling the API,

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.spacestudy.model.RoomInvestigatorMapping
at com.spacestudy.services.RoomService.retrieveReponsiblePerson(RoomService.java:210) ~[classes/:na]
at com.spacestudy.controller.RoomController.loadResponsiblePersonsMethod(RoomController.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
```

My RoomInvestigatorMapping.java like the following,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roominvestigatormapping")
public class RoomInvestigatorMapping implements Serializable
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "roominvestigatormapping_seq_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "roominvestigatormapping_seq_generator", sequenceName = "roominvestigatormapping_seq",allocationSize=1)

@Column(name="nroom_investigator_mapping_id",columnDefinition="serial")
public Integer nRoomInvestigatorMappingId;

@Column(name="nroom_allocation_id")
public Integer nRoomAllocationId;

@Column(name="ninvestigator_id")
public Integer nInvestigatorId;

@Min(0)
@Max(100)
@Column(name="npercentage_assigned")
public Integer nPercentageAssigned;

@Column(name="scomment")
public String scomment;

@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="ninvestigator_id",referencedColumnName="nemp_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Employee employee;

@ManyToOne(optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="nroom_allocation_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
public RoomDepartmentMapping roomDepartmentMapping; 

}
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Check your repository method, it should return List<Map<Stting,Object>>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**, let's create constructors with `parameters` that you need for `RoomInvestigatorMapping` and `Employee`, then you should add these lines:

For **RoomInvestigatorMapping**

```
public RoomInvestigatorMapping() {
     // Empty constructor
}

public RoomInvestigatorMapping(String sEmpName, Integer nEmpId,
                               Integer nRoomInvestigatorMappingId,
                               Integer nRoomAllocationId) {
     this.employee = new Employee(sEmpName, nEmpId);
     this.nRoomInvestigatorMappingId = nRoomInvestigatorMappingId;
     this.nRoomAllocationId = nRoomAllocationId;                    
}
```

For **Employee**

```
public Employee() {
     // Empty constructor
}

public Employee(String sEmpName, Integer nEmpId) {
     this.sEmpName = sEmpName;
     this.nEmpId = nEmpId;
}
```

**Second**, let's modify your query like:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.spacestudy.model.RoomInvestigatorMapping(emp.sEmpName as sEmpName, emp.nEmpId as nEmpId,"   
     + " roomInvest.nRoomInvestigatorMappingId as nRoomInvestigatorMappingId,"
     + " roomInvest.nRoomAllocationId as nRoomAllocationId) "
     + "FROM RoomInvestigatorMapping as roomInvest "
     + "INNER JOIN Employee  as emp "
     + "ON roomInvest.nInvestigatorId  = emp.nEmpId ")
List<RoomInvestigatorMapping> findInvestigatorUsingName();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Repository` interface `@Query` return a Map that is issue for class Casting.

you are selecting a new Map and expecting a `RoomInvestigatorMapping` entity that cannot done by Hibernate.

```
select new map(emp.sEmpName as sEmpName, emp.nEmpId as nEmpId, " + "roomInvest.nRoomInvestigatorMappingId as nRoomInvestigatorMappingId, " + "roomInvest.nRoomAllocationId as nRoomAllocationId)
```

The above query will return `List<Map<String, Object>>`.